# Making !suggest command for my discord server, and need it to dm me, the owner. Is it possible to dm a specific person?

Tags: python, command, bots, discord, discord.py

So im making a !suggest command for my discord server and i have it done except i need it to dm me the suggestion the person made. I can not find info on how to dm a specific person by ID or otherwise. Here is my coded command thus far:

```
async def suggest(server, suggestion):
    await server.owner.create_dm()
    await dm_channel.send("{} suggested this: '{}'".format(ctx.author.mention, suggestion))
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`client.get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user) to get your own `User` object, which has a `send` method that will send a DM to you over Discord.

```
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, suggestion):
    dm_user = client.get_user(1234567890) # Your Discord ID here
    await dm_user.send("{} suggested this: '{}'".format(ctx.author.mention, suggestion))

client.run('token')
```

Comment: This returns the error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'" help?

Comment: Make sure to replace `client.get_user(1234567890)` with your own user ID from Discord, otherwise this will return `None`

Comment: I have changed the code to this:

`@bot.command()
async def suggest(ctx, suggestion):
    ch = client.get_channel(*i had the id here*)
    await ch.send("{} suggested {}".format(ctx.author.mention, suggestion))`

upon further research, and it still returns the same error. It is going to send the suggestion to my private suggestions channel where i can review it.

Comment: `get_channel` will return a channel of that ID, not a user. For your purposes you need the user. Update your question with you code and your error so it can be reviewed